# Count objects in the individual folders of S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know we can easily count the total objects of S3 bucket with the below command, but how to get the count of objects in the individual folders of S3 bucket?

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/ --recursive | wc -l
```

For example, if the bucket has subfolders like below, I want to know the count of objects in each date folder

```
~$aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/ 
                       PRE 2019-01-01/
                       PRE 2019-01-02/
                       PRE 2019-01-03/
                       PRE 2019-01-04/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this Python3 script:

```py
import boto3
from pathlib import Path

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='ap-southeast-2')

folders = {}
bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('my-bucket')
for object in bucket.objects.all():
    path = Path(object.key).parent
    folders[path] = folders.get(path, 0) + 1

for folder in folders:
    print(folder, folders[folder])
```